# При смене почты не отправлются данные с формы

Tags: php, email, form

Поменял почту в PHP документе и после этого не приходят данные с формы на почту.
Пробовал (`mail, Google`), если вернуть старую почту, то все нормально.

Пользуюсь бесплатным хостингом SprintHost.

```
Вот форма HTML

<form class="form" id="form" name="form">

<input type="name" name="name" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Имя" >
<br>
<input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" id="inputTel" placeholder="Телефон">
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Заказать расчет</button>

</form>

и PHP документ 


<?php

$recepient = "maail@yandex.ru";
$siteName = "Сайтик";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $phone";

$pagetitle = "Заявка с сайта "$siteName"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\n From: $recepient");
```

Comment: скопируйте сюда ваш код, чтобы было яснее

Comment: @beg1nn3r также обратите внимание, что у хостинга могут быть проблемы с доставкой почты на mail.ru

Answer (score 1):

И ошибок никаких не выводит?
Попробуйте изменить строку

```
$pagetitle = "Заявка с сайта "$siteName"";
```

на

```
$pagetitle = "Заявка с сайта $siteName";
```

и точно так же здесь

```
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\n From: $recepient");
```

на

```
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n From: $recepient");
```

Comment: Решил проблему,это все хостинг. 
Написал в техподдержку,оказывается там лимит 20 сообщений в сутки.
Но,почему то когда ставил свою старую почту,раз в час да сообщение приходило,техподдержка ответила что это норм. 

А так спасибо)